# Get usage metrics for carbon or workshop in Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-carbon

We have a couple of workshop applications and carbon workspaces where we are interested in some aggregated user/usage metrics for example daily/weekly unique users. Are these numbers available somewhere such that we could present them in a simple overview?

I'm aware of the Usage tab in OMA however it is not granular enough on a per application basis for our need, but something similar to that for workshops/carbon would be great!

Comment: best way to do that is to ingest your own foundry logs and then calculate the metrics you want from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to request the data from your Palantir customer support team for that.

The data could be available but maybe it's not being ingested into your instance at the moment.

Comment: Ask for 'Quantum' data.